# Injection from A to B given injection from A^2 to B^2

Tags: functions

I wonder if given an injection $A^2 \rightarrow B^2$, there necesarrily exists an injection $A \rightarrow B$. And if there is, can you construct it canonically?
If we assume the axiom of choice, then non-existence of an injection implies existence of a surjection. So then this can be rephrased as given a surjection $A \rightarrow B$, construct a surjection $A^2 \rightarrow B^2$, which off course is possible canononically.
So my question is if we can find a canonical injection $A \rightarrow B$ given an injection $A^2 \rightarrow B^2$ without invoking the axiom of choice.

Comment: I don't see why would there be a canonical choice of injection. Let $A = \{0\}$ and $B = \{0,1\}$. Then $f(0,0) = (0,1)$ is injection $A^2\to B^2$. How would you define $\bar f(0)$ then? As $0$ or $1$?

Comment: It seems that this should be true from a simple cardinal argument: if $A^2$ has fewer elements than $B^2$ then certainly $A$ has fewer elements than $B$. But constructing the injection from $f$ without the axiom of choice doesn't look particularly easy. If $f = (f_1, f_2)$, then the injectivity of $f$ certainly does not imply any injectivity in $f_1$ nor in $f_2$.

Comment: @Ennar, may be canonical isn't the right word indeed. I mean a general recipe, just like how you can construct a bijection given an injection from $A$ to $B$ and $B$ to $A$.

Comment: @JelleBloemendaal you always have diagonal injection $A\to A^2$ that you can use but for $B^2\to B$ you need to pick projection and you can't do that consistently I think.